# UIDevice/NSUUID or part of them?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are creating some unique user identifier with :

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Which is great .

Then, under every user unique id (like this) , we have a few devices id's, which has to be *in some hardware device also, and must be short .*

They cant be that long , like the one you get with `UIDevice` .
They have to be unique but with 10-14 characters (numbers and letters) .

so for example take the first 10 chars of :

```
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
```

Question is, can i take only part of this unique to create other uniques which will be shorter version of it, and still be unique ?

Comment: Not exactly sure why you want it shorter. Storing on a server somewhere and concerned about space?

You really cant make it shorter. Its like giving just half of your drivers license. Chances are, you and someone else have the safe half, but unique full.

Comment: Because the hardware(which is different from software) has its limitations.

Comment: Could you split, then later combine the two halves? @feliun is right there is no way to say a UUID is unique unless it retains its entire length.

Comment: Simply put:  You have up to 20 membres, you give them an ID of 1 to 20, and you want to keep only the first number... It's possible to have same ID for various people. Enlarge your system to 1K members, with ID between 1 and 10K (members are less than possible ID), and you erase the last 2 digits... Same issue.

Comment: I am not sure you right. if i take 14 characters from NSUUID (instead of full of it ±25 ) i then get number of possibilities of many many millions ... then if you have even 100k users you are very far from even scratching that number.